# Metasploit msfrpcd with database

Tags: database, metasploit

I have a problem, I want to run Metasploit framework as a service, but it can not connect database if use "msfrpcd" tool. If I use msfconsole and "load msgrpc" is ok. So can you help me connect to the database when I use the "msfrpcd" tool. Thanks for your supports.

Answer (score 0):

Try starting the postgres service.

Try running these commnands

```
service postgres start
msfdb init
msfconsole
```

This should do the trick.